# Converting NSDate to NSString and NSdate of another Format

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using following method to convert NSDate to NSString

```
- (void)splitDateintoDateTime:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    strTime = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

The format of `date` is `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z`

I want separate NSDate values for `Date` and `Time` with format mentioned in the method.

Comment: What's the problem you are facing here?

Comment: so what's problem?? what are you getting in strDate & strTime?

Comment: I want to get NSDates for mentioned formats, that is, `dd/MM/yyyy` and `hh:mm a`

Comment: I am successfully able to retrieve the NSStrings. I want NSDates respectively for the same format

Comment: try **NSDate *dt = [formatter datefromString:strDate]**

Comment: put your original date value here

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati : I tried, not working :(

Comment: You can't get only "dd/MM/yyyy" date in NSDate. date must be followed by "00:00:00 +0000" time timezone. instead you can use Date as NSString.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)splitDateintoDateTime:(NSDate *)date
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy";
   NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: date];
   NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
   timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm z";
   NSString *dateString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate: date];
   }
```